# Is the independent streak in the Dniestrian countries due to their Phanariot heritage?

Tags: history, moldova, demographics

I have always been puzzled by the independence of the people along the Dniester River and their various countries such as Moldova, Transnistria and Bessarabia. Why aren't they a natural part of Romania or the Ukraine?

At first I thought it might be because of a Muslim heritage, but going backwards in time, it seems that the region even pre-dates that and originally had a [Phanariot heritage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phanariotes). It appears that the Muslim influence possibly just followed on the tailcoats of what was originally a Greek culture.

Is that the basic difference, that the Dniestrian countries had an ancient Greek influence that differentiated them from their Slavic neighbors? Or is it something else, Cossacks for example?

Answer (score 6):

I see nothing so romantic.

Moldova became separated from Romania as a result of land deals between the Ottoman and Russian Empires, and later between the Communist governments of Romania and the Soviet Union.

During Soviet Control, quite large Slavic populations built up, especially in Transnistria (which had never been part of Romania), and many Russians had positions of authority. Russians lost out in when the country became independent. Romanian Moldovans took power and found that they didn't want to give up control and merge with Romania. But in Transnistria, the Slavic majority didn't want to be part of a Romanian/Moldovan country, and they declared independence. The Moldovan army is not powerful enough to stage a showdown with Transnistria, especially as it could be backed by its powerful neighbours.

There is now very little Muslim influence (the country is more than 98% Christian) and no ancient Greek culture.  The independent-mindedness is a consequence of recent politics, not ancient culture.